# Should I update my arXiv submission after it's been reviewed and published OA in a Springer journal?

Tags: publications, arxiv, open-access

I recently had a paper accepted in a Springer journal, which allows "Open Choice", meaning that the article can be made Open Access. My institution covers the charges, so I agreed to do it and now it's in process of publication.

My question is: when I first submitted the manuscript, I also put a version on the arXiv and on my webpage. Now in the accepted version there are a couple of updates coming from referee revisions. I already put the new version in my webpage, since I know I can do that.

But what about the arXiv? When using non-Open Access, there is a 12 month embargo period. But it's not clear for me from
https://www.springer.com/gp/open-access/authors-rights/self-archiving-policy/2124
whether I can update the version with the accepted version in the arXiv. I don't care for the journal typesetting; I'm happy with just putting the revisions in my own LaTeX file.

Can I do it without issue?

Comment: I don't know about the de-jure part, but de-facto you can (and should) always update arxiv preprints with corrections.

Comment: The link you provided says "Prior versions of the article published on non-commercial pre-print servers like arXiv.org can remain on these servers and/or can be updated with the author’s accepted version." From this it seems that (a) the 12 month embargo period never applies to arXiv and (b) You can also update the arXiv version with the accepted version. It does not seem this changes with the open access option.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I do not agree with "always" in your statement. There are (and they are not rare to my knowledge) situations when after trying to follow the reviewer's "suggestions" the paper changes, and not in the better side. In this case I would definitely keep the original version.

Comment: @Artem: Ah, good point!

Comment: @Artem:  Yeah, it's important that sometimes refereeing makes  a paper marginally worse.  When that happens, it can be good to leave the older arXiv version alone.

Answer (score 4):

Under Springer [Open Choice](https://www.springer.com/gp/open-access/springer-open-choice), you retain copyright and the journal releases the published article under a CC-BY license.

So:

- By the terms of CC-BY, **everyone can make a copy the published paper and redistribute it under the same license**, including on Arxiv.
- Even better: **you, the copyright holder, can relicense the paper to anyone**, with the terms you want. As long as you don't give them an "exclusive right to distribute", of course, because you cannot take back the rights you have already granted others.

Some Open Choice journals use CC-BY-NC, though which may make redistribution under the first method trickier, because Arxiv does not have an option for CC-BY-NC. The other method is always ok, though.

Note: I am not a lawyer.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the link you provided is somehow contradictory.

So, for the open access option, you can publish the final "official" pdf in any website and/or depository (as you have paid the publications costs and you retain the rights).

For the non-open access option, the information are more confusing. The copyright transfer statement says:

> "Authors may self-archive the author’s accepted manuscript of their
>   articles on their own websites. Authors may also deposit this version
>   of the article in any repository, provided it is only made publicly
>   available 12 months after official publication or later. He/ she may
>   not use the publisher's version (the final article), which is posted
>   on SpringerLink and other Springer websites, for the purpose of
>   self-archiving or deposit. Furthermore, the author may only post
>   his/her version provided acknowledgement is given to the original
>   source of publication and a link is inserted to the published article
>   on Springer's website.  The link must be provided by inserting the DOI
>   number of the article in the following sentence: “The final
>   publication is available at Springer via http://dx.doi.org/[insert
>   DOI]”."

From this it seems that:

1. The accepted version of the manuscript (but not the final pdf) can be published in your own website.
2. The accepted version of the manuscript can be deposited to any repository as long as it is available publicly at least 12 months after the publication.
3. You **cannot** use the official pdf generated by the publisher anywhere.
4. For 1 and 2, you have to add a link to the official pdf.

The second part reads:

> Prior versions of the article published on non-commercial pre-print
>   servers like arXiv.org can remain on these servers and/or can be
>   updated with the author’s accepted version. The final published
>   version (in PDF or HTML/XML format) cannot be used for this purpose.

From my understanding, you can have the accepted (or earlier) version on arXiv. But still, it doesn't mention the clause about the 12 month time to be publicly available. Since the last part is not the one you sign when you transfer the copyright, it is probably not legally binding and you are still obliged to keep the 12 month period before you have it publicly available.

I.e. "Any repository" is the legal term and seems to include the non-commercial pre-print repositories.

Now, since you plan to have it open access, there is nothing to worry about. But if you still consider the non-open access option, I would refrain from having the accepted version of the manuscript and I would add a link to the official pdf as well. I would also contact the editor or the support of the journal to clarify if non-commercial pre-print repositories are OK and I wouldn't sign something that is unclear to me.

Contacting them might also lead to a clarification of the instructions or update the Copyright transfer statement you have to sign (which would help other researchers avoid a potential issue).

As a last comment, I suspect that if it would be possible to submit the accepted version to any non-commercial pre-print repository, it kind of negates the whole point of them selling access to your paper...